# How to do division of columns when importing to postgres (python script)?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to import price into a column as sales/sold. This is what I have in my python script:

```
arg = {
    'sold': row[4].strip(),
    'sales': row[6].strip(),
   }

cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO 
    "sales"("sold","price","sales")
     select %(sold)s,
        float(%(sales)s)/float(%(sold)s),
        %(sales)s,
    ;""", arg)
```

I get this error when I run the script:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'18'"
LINE 10:                 float('18')/float('3'),
```

How do I convert to float? Also, what would be the easiest way to set division by 0 to 0?

Comment: You need to set price as a field in are and then calculate it before passing in

Answer (score 1):

Cast the parameters to numeric otherwise psycopg2 will render them as strings

```
arg = {
    'sold': int(row[4]),
    'sales': float(row[6])
}
```

Since they will be cast to numeric there is no need to `strip()`

To make the division by 0 to be 0 use a `case` clause:

```
cur.execute("""
    insert into sales (sold, price, sales)
    select
        %(sold)s,
        case
            when %(sold)s = 0 then 0
            else %(sales)s / %(sold)s
        end,
        %(sales)s,
    ;""", arg
)
```